# Bootstrap Modal won't fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap modal to display post details on wordpress. But I have an issue with the modal. The whole screen is grey, I can see the modal but nothing is clickable. I can exit this mode by hitting "esc" key. I think it's a js issue, but can't figure out. I have jquery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css loaded.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-39">
<div class="col-lg-4 imgWrap">
<img width="500" height="332" src="img/myimage.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="myimage" />          <h2><span>Title 39</span></h2>
      <p class="imgDescription">Description 39</p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </a>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-39" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel-39" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel-39">Title 39</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
        <img width="500" height="332" src="img/myimage.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="marrakech" />                                      </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8E8En/

Did I miss something?
Thanks,

Comment: x in upper right corner isn't clickable too?

Comment: Added a fiddle, the x is working in your code? what is not clickable @Ali?

Comment: it seems that I have some js scripts (wordpress ?) that block my clics. If I test it inside a simple HTML template, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like there is some elements have `z-index` higher then your modal.

Try to inspect your website using `firebug` or chrome developer tools to figure it out

Or try this style:

```
.modal {
    z-index: 10000
}
```

You can read more about `z-index` from MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Finally it was a stylesheet that caused this. When I commented it, everything went just fine. Thanks everybody for your quick answers.